# Is emitting a signal from C++ to QML for reading a Q_PROPERTY a synchronous event?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

Using Qt 5.1 I have this:

```
Q_PROPERTY(float d1 MEMBER data1 NOTIFY datas_changed_signal)
Q_PROPERTY(float d2 MEMBER data2 NOTIFY datas_changed_signal)

....

void setOBJ(nobj){
        obj=nobj; //these are pointers to a data structure
        data1=nobj->data1(); //assign to member of this class
        data2=nobj->data2();

        emit datas_changed_signal();
    }
```

My class receives a pointer to some data, `nobj` and then I want my QML to have access to this data. Actually `nobj` contains far more than just 2 data items, but I express here for simplicity.

I want to know a couple things. First, what happens when `setOBJ` is called often, quickly. Is there a risk that the QML will get notified but not read the `MEMBER` (data1 or data2) before `setOBJ` is called again? Could the QML miss some updates because of this? This would happen if it was asynchronous, for example. Or, can I always count on the QML getting the data every time this signal above it emitted?

Second, it seems to me there is some unnecessary overhead here in creating intermediate data members to store the data from the passed-in object `nobj`.  I tried this instead:

```
    Q_PROPERTY(float d1 MEMBER obj->data1() NOTIFY datas_changed_signal)
```

But MOC doesn't seem to like using `Q_PROPERTY` in this way (doesn't compile). Would there be a similar alternative?

Update: I found [this method (link)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#invoking-qml-methods) that seems like a viable alternative to Q_PROPERTY for sending data from C++ to QML, I could just send my data pieces as arguments to a QML function. Is that a good alternative?

Answer (score 4):

Signals and slots are implemented synchronously, by default, and are always processed in order even when implemented asynchronously and even passed across thread boundaries.  So you don't need to worry that your QML will be getting the signals in the wrong order.

And, in fact, by default signals actually fire off all the bound object code immediately.  IE, this:

```
emit datas_changed_signal();
```

Is almost like calling:

```
slotFunction1();
slotFunction2();
...
```

So any attached QML javascript (onDatas_changed_signal) will be called immediately, in fact.

Signals and slots are the preferred way to send data to QML, as it provides much greater support for QML being independent from the C++ underlying model, so I'd stick with properties, signals and slots.  Your QML code may someday need to expand and have multiple things happen on a propery change, and that's simply easy and slick if you do it via a property rather than calling a QML function directly.

Comment: I just did a test sending the same data to QML from C++ using Q_PROPERTY and sending the same data via an invokable method. My data changes often and the invokable method had no loss of data. But the Q_PROPERTY when using onDataMember changed signals dropped a lot of data; I really suspect there is some kind of queuing operation going on behind the scenes and that it is possible the C++ data might change before the QML sees it.

Comment: Are you sure your slots are being called on data change?

Comment: In general, it seems to me that you might need to consider synchronicity more when using QML (more than say just using signals internal to your business logic), since QML often is invoking native GUI functions (having state such as modality) that you might need to allow to complete before handling other signals.  A symptom of synchronicity problems might be different behaviours on different platforms.